# Getting Disabled Dropdown values in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am pretty new to MVC. In my form i have a disabled dropdown control whose value is not getting passed to the Model during submit as it is disabled. I tried using a hidden field like below

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DepartmentID, new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Text = "Item 1", Value = "1" }, new SelectListItem { Text = "Item 2", Value = "2", Selected = true } })

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DepartmentID)
```

Both of the above statement produce controls having the same id so i was not sure can i get the value of the dropdown in the hidden field.

I could use a different id while creating the hidden variable and assign the dropdown value it it using jquery.

I just want to know if i can achieve the same using the Hidden field having the same id as shown in the above code ??

Comment: can you add the code for the controller action that is handling this view?

Comment: @SOfanatic - it has nothing to do with the control, the browser won't submit values from disabled controls.

Comment: @MystereMan yes I know, I just thought Mako meant that not even the `HiddenFor` was showing in the post.

Comment: @SOfanatic - he's not saying it doesn't work, he's asking if it will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Form Fields are not submitted by ID, they're submitted by name.  It's ok for there to be two controls with the same name.  However, it's invalid HTML to have two elements with the same id.

You can set a different ID but keep the same name like this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.DepartmentID, new { id="DepartmentID2" })
```

Comment: This solution also works on razor page, so cheers :)